# Как осуществить выделение цветом отрицательных элементов в двумерном массиве DataGridView? (C#)

Tags: c#, массивы, datagridview

Разрабатывается программа Windows Form.
Есть масив - `int [,] a`, размерность которого задается пользователем вручную в выделенном диапазоне `DataGridView1.RowCount = n;`
`DataGridView1.ColumnCount = m` (по умолчанию, 5x5). Ячейки заполняются рандомными значениями `a[i, j] = ran.Next(-20, 50)`.

Определенная часть массива, после генерации имеет отрицательные значения. Как можно выделить цветом только такие ячейка (со знаком "-")?

Пытался через что-то подобное сделать, только под свои условия, но в большинстве случаев получаю ошибку `Оператор "<" невозможно применить к операнду типа "object" и "int".`

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Value == 3)
        row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    else if (row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Value == 2)
        row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Буду благодарен, если поможете разобраться :)

Comment: Как значения из массива попадают в грид? / Если совпадение значений в массиве и гриде всегда точное, то можно обращаться к массиву - тогда не нужно приведение типов. / Для раскраски ячеек есть специальное событие: CellFormatting.

Comment: После обозначения пользователем размерности DataGridView, прописанный индексатор перебирает допустимые ячейки и заполняет их значениями, в диапазоне (-20 до 50), как было указано в вопросе / Совпадение, предполагаемо точное / Благодарю, рассмотрю это событие :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли про приведение типов.

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var cell = row.Cells[someColumnIndex];
    int number = (int)cell.Value;
    if (number == 3)
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    else if (number == 2)
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

[Упаковка-преобразование и распаковка-преобразование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

Кстати, есть способ написать этот код немного проще, но нужен C# 8.0. К сожалению, у вас не указана версия дотнета или языка.

Comment: Как 8.0 в данном примере будет проще?

Comment: @Blackmeser `cell.Style.BackColor = number switch { 3 => Color.Blue, 2 => Color.Red }`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь :)

Comment: @aepot а если number не 2 и не 3 - ``cell.Style.BackColor`` не будет изменён? ``UPDATE:`` всё, проверил, будет InvalidOperationException, корректней будет ``cell.Style.BackColor = number switch { 3 => Color.Blue, 2 => Color.Red, _ => cell.Style.BackColor };``